# Loop ignores change of variable from a subshell in the background

Tags: shell-script, scripting, background-process

I wrote a script that contains an `until` loop. This loop should run till a boolean variable is set to `true` from outside the loop. Unfortunately the loop ignores that the variable has been set to true and keeps running. Here are a few lines which generate this problem:

```
boolean=false
{ sleep 5 && boolean=true && echo "boolean is true now" ; } &
{ until [ "$boolean" = true ] ; do sleep 1 && echo $boolean ; done ; } &&
echo "boolean is true now: $boolean"
```

The output this generates is:

```
false
false
false
false
boolean is true now
false
false
false
...
```

How can I make the loop exit when the `boolean` is set to `true`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `&` character makes a background process. A background process is executed asynchronously in a subshell. Variables can be passed from a parent shell to sub shell, not the other way around. However, you can do a workaround if you are really in need of the value set in the child shell:

```
boolean=$(mktemp) && echo "false" >$boolean
{ sleep 5 && echo true >$boolean && echo "boolean is true now" ; } &
{ until [ "$(cat $boolean)" = "true" ] ; do sleep 1 && cat $boolean ; done ; } &&
echo "boolean is true now: $(cat $boolean)"
```

That makes a temporary file whose content is the boolean value. In the `until` loop that file is checked until it contains true.

**Notice:**

I recommend to do the following in your script (if possible):

```
{ sleep 5 && echo "background process done" ; } &
wait
echo "continue in foregound."
```

`wait` waits for the background process to finish.

Comment: Thanks. This works fine. 
I would use wait but the background process in my script is always running.

Comment: What's the point of running something asynchronously, then waiting for it to finish? Just run it normally.

Comment: @immibis I think that between the job and the wait the asker has some code.

Answer (score 13):

It's possible to use signals to communicate between the foreground and background shells:

```
#!/bin/bash

# global variable for foreground shell
boolean=false

# register a signal handler for SIGUSR1
trap handler USR1

# the handler sets the global variable
handler() { boolean=true; }

echo "before: $boolean"

# Here, "$$" is the pid of the foreground shell
{ sleep 5; kill -USR1 $$; echo "finished background process"; } &

# busy waiting
until $boolean; do 
    echo "waiting..."
    sleep 1
done

echo "after: $boolean"
```

output

```
before: false
waiting...
waiting...
waiting...
waiting...
waiting...
finished background process
after: true
```

Comment: +1 Signals are the right way to pass asynchronous notifications between processes.

Comment: Using USR1, how to pass value instead of asynchronous notifications between processes?

Answer (score 4):

You mistakenly assume that the `boolean` you set to true in the second line is the same boolean that you test for in the `until` statement. That is not the case, you start new process, with a new shell in the background and `boolean` (the one you test for), never gets assigned.